# Action Bar gets hidden when keyboard is open. How to prevent this?

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

I have a `Coordinator Layout`, which contains `AppBar Layout` and one `Relative Layout`.

Relative layout contains one `ScrollView` and a `EditText`.

Firstly, Whenever I used to tap edit text to input text, keyboard open up and hid the edit text field. `ActionBar` is visible on the top.

When I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest for the activity, edit text field is still hidden behind the keyboard. `Actionbar` is visible at screen top.

But When I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, my `Edittext` field was visible just above the keyboard, but now `Actionbar` goes out of screen.

I want to have action bar always visible and edit text field visible above keyboard.

Please help me with the fix!

content_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />
    </ScrollView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:background="@drawable/input_edit_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_input_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_home.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What was your solution buddy?